# Finding a solution to a non-square matrix using existing approximate solution

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have a small, non-square matrix, A, with *m* rows and *n* columns. The number of columns (*n*) exceeds the number of rows (*m*). I also have a vector, *b*, which I can generate to arbitrary precision. I'm looking to solve for x in:

```
Ax = b
```

I have an approximate solution vector, *x*, which was generated to 7 digits (single-precision floating point real numbers).  I would like to extend this out to 16 digits (double-precision), but I no longer have access to the additional rows of the matrix, A, that were used to solve the matrix in the traditional sense.

Is there any way that I could use my approximate solution vector, *x*, to obtain a more precise solution vector? I have tried  formulating the problem as a system of equations, adding constraints on *x* using inequalities, and using NSolve, but that did not produce a solution.

**EDIT:**

The simplest case that I have is 7x7, but can be reduced to 6x7:

```
A={{2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0},
 {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1},
 {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0},
 {0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

b = {0.298795946144997291830, .22567858284542534131, 
  0.10553546373877704683, 0.13050521647379568282, 
  0.083686154626386665888, 0.097801595273620974917, 
  0.057997040896996996406}

appX={.05799704, .04890080, .02214971, .04070086, .03938674, .02455175, .01213254};
```

Notice that A.appX is very close to b.

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you want. This system has many solutions. `LeastSquares[A,b]` is one of them and adding any linear combination of the vectors in `NullSpace[A]` leads the general solution.

Comment: I have one specific solution, x, and I would like to enhance the precision of my existing specific solution.

Comment: You can refine you solution, e.g. with `Transpose[A].LinearSolve[A.Transpose[A], b, 
  Method -> {"Krylov", "StartingVector" -> A.x, Tolerance -> 10^-15}]`. This calls uses the `"BiCGStab"` algorithm for iterative refinement. Will only work well for smal matrices if you don't have a good preconditioner at hand.

Comment: Thanks. However, it seems to converge on the same solution that LeastSquares[A,b] finds, which is, unfortunately, not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, this is leading nowhere. I need the matrix `A` and the vectors `b` and `x`.

Comment: updated with example.